# Make a list drag and droppable

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, drag-and-drop, instance

I am building a football manager sim. I have a List of Players and when the game starts the Players are instanced into the SquadList using PlayerDisplayPrefabs. I would like this SquadList to be drag and droppable with the ability to swap players and their stats in and out of the first team.

I have added the drag functionality to the Prefab but in order to add the drop functionality I need to have each Prefab instance onto its own Panel rather than the SquadList Panel.

But if I put landing Panels onto the SquadList Panel my list is instanced below these Panels and not on top.

[This is what it looks like at the moment. I would like each item to be instanced into its own landing spot rather than below them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFHJM.jpg)

Thia is the code I'm using to instance the list into the SquadDisplay Panel.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class SquadDisplay : MonoBehaviour
{

public Transform targetTransform;
public PlayerDisplay playerDisplayPrefab;
public List<Player> items = new List<Player>();



// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
        foreach (Player item in items)
    {
        PlayerDisplay display = (PlayerDisplay)Instantiate(playerDisplayPrefab);
        display.transform.SetParent(targetTransform, false);
        display.Prime(item);
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
   
}

}
```

Any ideas? Thanks JP

Answer (score -1):

You are setting parent, but never changing actual transform position isn't that what you intended?

Comment: hi tomasz. It was initially but I would now like to have a squad list of 15 slots and then instantiate each player into its own individual slot. I can set up the squad list with the 15 landing slots and if I set the target transform to the first slot it puts the first item in there but how would i get it to put the second item in the second slot and the third in the the third slot etc?

Comment: You can create an array of 15 GameObjects that would be potential positions for newly instatiated Players(setting those game objects in editor).Then you create "for loop" for 15 times and increment "i" in this loop 15 times.With each incrementation you instantiate player and set his position equall to GameObject array at [i] index .

Comment: for(int i = 0; i<=14;i++)
        {
            Instantiate(WhateverYouInstantiate, avaiblePLayerPositinsInSlot[i].transform.position, transform.rotation);
        }